# Protobuf data serializer

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

this  dataserializer is great for performance. but I keep getting stuck on datacolumns that has datatype of System.Object causing the serializer to throw an exception:Cannot serialize data column of type 'System.Object'.

is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protobuf format is designed to suit scenarios where the data is predictable to the receiver, and does not suit "object" scenarios very well, however, depending on the data layout a few things are possible:

- if the "object" data is a nested message of some kind, then you can mark the member as "DynamicType=true" as part of the ProtoMemberAttribute decoration; this then includes some metadata, but as a protobuf-net specific extension. It will not be very portable between systems
- if the "object" data is really one of a handful of known types, typically things like int/DateTime/float etc then there are some ways of representing that with inheritance (non-generic base type, multiple specific T subtypes). Again, this will not be very portable between platforms

I can illustrate either if I understand the model more.

Answer (score 0):

From [the protobuf-net getting started page](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted)

> Unlike XmlSerializer, the member-names are not encoded in the data -
>   instead, you must pick an integer to identify each member.

In other words, you need to help the serializer by defining on *each and every class* how to serialize and deserialize it. If it is really a requirement to be able to automatically serialize all classes based on System.Object, protobuf is not for you.