# Serializing IConvertible field with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a class:

```
internal class Value
{
    internal IConvertible Min { get; set; }
}
```

and a test case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Custom_IConvertible()
{
    RuntimeTypeModel.Default.
        Add(typeof(Value), false).
        Add(1, "Min");

    RuntimeTypeModel.Default.
        Add(typeof(IConvertible), false);

    var val = new Value {Min = true};
    var result = Serializer.DeepClone(val);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, result.Min);
}
```

that throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected sub-type: System.Boolean
```

But I cannot add boolean as a subtype of IConvertible, because I will get:

```
System.ArgumentException: Data of this type has inbuilt behaviour, and 
cannot be added to a model in this way: System.Boolean
```

As I see it, IConvertible is only implemented by BCL base types and this scenario should be working just OK. What am I missing here?

---

Inspired by Marc's response below, I rewrote my sample.

Having a class:

```
internal abstract class Value
{
    internal IConvertible Min { get; set; }

    internal static Value Create<T>(T min) where T :IConvertible
    {
        return new ValueT<T> {Min = min};
    }

    internal sealed class ValueT<T> : Value where T : IConvertible
    {
        internal new T Min
        {
            get { return (T) base.Min; }
            set { base.Min = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

and a test case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Custom_IConvertible()
{
    RuntimeTypeModel.Default.
        Add(typeof(Value), false).
        AddSubType(10, typeof(Value.ValueT<bool>));

    RuntimeTypeModel.Default.
        Add(typeof(Value.ValueT<bool>), false).
        Add(1, "Min");

    var val = Value.Create(true);
    var result = Serializer.DeepClone(val);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, result.Min);
}
```

I get an exception when calling Add(1, "Min"):

```
System.ArgumentException: Unable to determine member: Min
Parameter name: memberName
```

However, it will work just fine if I were to define a class as (same code, but with attributes):

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(ValueT<int>))]
internal abstract class Value
{
    internal IConvertible Min { get; set; }

    internal static Value Create<T>(T min) where T :IConvertible
    {
        return new ValueT<T> {Min = min};
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    internal sealed class ValueT<T> : Value where T : IConvertible
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        internal new T Min
        {
            get { return (T) base.Min; }
            set { base.Min = value; }
        }
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Custom_IConvertible()
{
    var val = Value.Create(true);
    var result = Serializer.DeepClone(val);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, result.Min);
}
```

but I cannot use attributes.

Is it a bug or I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

That isn't going to work. protobuf-net works against data contracts (essentially), and `IConvertible` is *not* a contract - the actual value at runtime could be anything. protobuf-net wants to know *in advance* what it is.

There *is* support for interfaces in protobuf-net, but that is for different scenarios.

The fact that they are BCL primitives is irrelevant; and for exactly the same reason, `internal object Min {get;set;}` would fail.

tl;dr: that is not a supported scenario.

---

Here's a re-working that *can* work (note that for convenience I've used attributes for configuration, but it would work via runtime configuration too):

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(ValueImpl<int>))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(ValueImpl<float>))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(ValueImpl<double>))]
// other types you want to support
internal abstract class Value
{
    public static Value Create<T>(T value) where T : IConvertible
    {
        return new ValueImpl<T> { Min = value };
    }
    public IConvertible Min { get { return MinImpl;} set { MinImpl = value;}}
    protected abstract IConvertible MinImpl {get;set;}
    [ProtoContract]
    public sealed class ValueImpl<T> : Value where T : IConvertible
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public new T Min { get; set; }
        protected override IConvertible MinImpl
        {
            get { return Min; }
            set { Min = (T)value; }
        }
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {       
        var val = Value.Create(true);
        var result = Serializer.DeepClone(val);

        bool x = (bool)val.Min; // true
    }
}
```

Comment: In a post [Protobuf data serializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953662/protobuf-data-serializer), you suggested there are some ways to achieve this (second bullet). And in [Getting 'A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization' exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491933/getting-a-reference-tracked-object-changed-reference-during-deserialization-ex) there is a scenario with object, however trying that on my sample with object instead of IConvertible still fails despite the fix. I tried it on latest v2 from nuget.

Comment: @andriys yes, but those ways involve changing the structure of that model. It depends which is more important: (de)serializing the data, or keeping that particular structure.

Comment: so what are my options in each case? Does this mean that I need to create DTOs to make serialization possible?

Comment: that's a nice solution. However, I can't get it working with type model. Please, look at my updated question.